# Exibir se a pessoa é maior de idade ou não

Tags: visualg, portugol

Alguém pode me ajudar com um exercício no visualg? é o seguinte: o exercício pede assim:

> Escreva um programa que leia a idade de uma pessoa. Ao final, exiba se essa pessoa é maior de idade ou não.
>
> Console
>
> Qual sua idade: 17.
>
> maior de idade = FALSO

Quero que apresente no final resultado falso para quem é menor de 18 anos e verdadeiro para quem é maior de 18 anos.

```
algoritmo"exercício"
var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
  Idade: inteiro
  Valor: logico

inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
  Idade <- (18)
  escreva ("Digite sua idade: ")
  leia (idade)
  escreva
fimalgoritmo
```

O código que eu fiz é esse acima mas está dando erro.

Answer (score 3):

Falta adicionar a verificação/comparação da idade com o valor desejado 18 anos, isso é feito com a instrução `se`.

```
se (idade >= 18) entao
   escreva ("maior de idade")
senao
   escreva ("menor de idade")
fimse
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```
 algoritmo"exercicio"
 var

 idade: inteiro

 inicio
 // Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 

 escreva ("Digite sua idade: ")
 leia (idade)
 se(idade>=18)entao
 escreval("MAIOR DE IDADE")
 senao

 escreval(idade," anos idade")
 escreval("CONSIDERADO MENOR DE IDADE")
 fimse
 fimalgoritmo
```